# Only url changes not the view or component onclick anchor tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to access the component view from the menu in navbar, but whenever I click on link , only the url changes not the view.

My code:

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Index />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
const routing = (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={withRouter(App)} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={withRouter(Register)} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
);


const Store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    routing,
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={Store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Header.js

```
<ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-list-item">
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-list-item">
          <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
      </li>            
 </ul>
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should use `withRouter` in components where you export them not in the `Route`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually render your Routes rather than put them into your redux store.

Also, no need to wrap your components with `withRouter` since they are already receiving the props from the Route component.

```
const Store = createStore(allReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    </Switch>
  </Provider>
</Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: I've basically rewritten your case to be like it is in basic react-router setup. Please refer to this basic example from the documentation and try to see how it is different from your code. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution of my own question.

First of all i written the routing in app.js and bind everything in browserrouter like this.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
         <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```